# Bash Permission denied when using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to concatenate a few files using ffmpeg, but I am getting this error message when I run the command:

```
-bash: /path/to/file/sound.ogg: Permission denied
```

I am logged in as a root user so i'm not sure why this error is happening

Comment: 1. Don't log in a root. 2. Apparently root doesn't have necessary permissions to either read or write (whichever you're trying to do) there.

Comment: To get any further, you should include the whole ffmpeg command you're running and the whole output, as well as the permissions on that directory and of that file if it exists.